# How can I automatically focus the button after choose an item with the select picker?

Tags: jquery, html, class, listbox, focus

When the user choose an item from the list box, the focus remain there, so if he press "enter" it remains there. I'd like to automatically change the focus after the pick.

I'm using this jquery function:

```
$(function() {
  $("nextStep").focus();
});
```

"nextStep" is the class of the button and it works, but I'd like to make it happen when the attribute of the combobox aria-expanded is false. Can you explain me how can I do this please?

This is the listbox:

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" 
data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="tn_workType" 
title="Disoccupato" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="filter-option pull-left">Disoccupato</span>&nbsp;
  <span class="bs-caret">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </span>
</button>
```

This is the nextStep button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-white btn-rounded nextStep" 
tabindex="0">Avanti →</a>
```

Comment: if `nextStep` is a class, should it not be `$(".nextStep").focus()` then

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
$('select').change(function (e) {
   $('.nextStep').focus();
});   
  $('.nextStep').click(function(){
  alert("Avanti buttonn clicked")
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<select class="btn btn-toogle btn-default">
<option>Option1</option>
<option>Option2</option>
</select>

When the user choose an item from the list box, the focus remain there, so if he press "enter" it remains there. I'd like to automatically change the focus after the pick.

I'm using this jquery function:

$(function() {
  $("nextStep").focus();
});
"nextStep" is the class of the button and it works, but I'd like to make it happen when the attribute of the combobox aria-expanded is false. Can you explain me how can I do this please?

This is the listbox:


This is the nextStep button:

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-white btn-rounded nextStep" 
tabindex="0">Avanti →</a>
```